# How to pivot this data and reorganize everything in just one row?

Tags: google-bigquery

I´m very new to BigQuery but i´m trying almost everything to get my data organized. I´m tracking results in each of my game levels, that way i can overview if people is getting stuck in any level. Consider i´m using Unity3D and this line of code to track my events:

```
FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("Levels", "Level_" + LevelInt.ToString(), trophyInt);
```

Where (Levels) is the **event**,
(Level_ + number_of_level) is the **key** parameter
and (trophyInt) is the **value**.

I run a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(event_dim.name) as Levels,
event_dim.params.key as level,
event_dim.params.value.int_value as value,
FROM
TABLE_DATE_RANGE(mytable_ANDROID.app_events_, TIMESTAMP('2017-05-10'), TIMESTAMP('2017-05-14'))
WHERE event_dim.name = 'Levels' 
  AND event_dim.params.key = 'Level_2' 
  AND user_dim.app_info.app_version = '1.9.3a' 
GROUP BY level, value
ORDER BY value desc
```

The result is this:

[This table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGi9W.png)

Well, i´d like to have the table in just one row, having only:

**Level_number | Trophies0 | Trophies1 | Trophies2 | Trophies3**

I´ve been trying with many examples from stackoverflow but none of these work for me.

In addition i´d like to know if it´s possible to query all the data from all my levels at the same time. I mean, in the above query i set event_dim.params.key = 'Level_2' but imagine i want to see my 100 levels at the same time, could it be possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're new to BigQuery, I would really recommend getting started using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) instead, since that's the preferred SQL dialect going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to pivot this data ...

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT
  level AS Level_number,
  MAX((value = 0) * Levels) AS Trophies0, 
  MAX((value = 1) * Levels) AS Trophies1, 
  MAX((value = 2) * Levels) AS Trophies2, 
  MAX((value = 3) * Levels) AS Trophies3
FROM (
  SELECT 
    COUNT(event_dim.name) AS Levels,
    event_dim.params.key AS level,
    event_dim.params.value.int_value AS value,
  FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(mytable_ANDROID.app_events_, TIMESTAMP('2017-05-10'), TIMESTAMP('2017-05-14'))
  WHERE event_dim.name = 'Levels' 
    AND event_dim.params.key = 'Level_2' 
    AND user_dim.app_info.app_version = '1.9.3a' 
  GROUP BY level, value
)
GROUP BY Level_number
```

> i want to see my 100 levels at the same time, could it be possible?

Just comment below line in query

```sql
    AND event_dim.params.key = 'Level_2'
```

or, if you also have keys other than just Level_NNN so you want to limit query to those - just change this line to something like

```sql
    AND event_dim.params.key LIKE 'Level_%'
```